# Why write GRR with the relative tangent sheaf?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, kt.k-theory-and-homology, intersection-theory, chern-classes

The first published version of the Grothendieck-Riemann-Roch theorem, GRR for short, was written in the form
$$
\operatorname{ch}(f_!\alpha).\operatorname{Td}(Y)
=
f_*\left(\operatorname{ch}(\alpha).\operatorname{Td}(X)\right)
$$
for $f\colon X\to Y$ and $\alpha\in K(X),$ where of course $\operatorname{Td}(X)=\operatorname{td}(\mathscr T_X).$ However it seems to me that the vast majority of later publications, most notably Fulton's *Intersection theory*, the formulation
$$
\operatorname{ch}(f_!\alpha)
=
f_*\left(\operatorname{ch}(\alpha).\operatorname{td}(\mathscr T_f)\right)
$$
is used, where $\mathscr T_f$ is the relative tangent sheaf or something similar to it (the vitual tangent sheaf etc.).

Q1: *Why is the second formulation preferable?*

I would think the first one is better as it does not only measure to what extent the chern character fails to be a natural transformation between the covariant K-homology and Chow homology functors, but actually shows a canonical way how to modify it to be one.

Q2: *Are the two formulations equivalent?*

Surely they are when we are discussing proper maps between sonsingular quasprojective schemes over a field, but how about in more general contexts? I would think they are always equivalent, by the virue of the multiplicativity of the Todd character and the projection formula, but I am very likely missing something.

Comment: One reason is just because people may want to compute $ch(f_!a)$ and the second formulation tells you how to do that.

Comment: The second version is also more general. If $X$ or $Y$ are singular, then the terms in  first statement are undefined, but $\mathcal{T}_f$ may still be defined, e.g. when $f$ is smooth and proper.

Comment: Well, there are ways of defining Todd classes even for singular varieties. One can take the Baum-Fulton-MacPhearson natural transformation $\tau\colon K_0\to A_{\mathbb Q}$ and define  the homology Todd class $\tau_X(\mathscr O_X).$ For locally complete intersections in nonsingular varieties that reduces to $\operatorname{td}(\mathscr T_X)\cap [X],$ the Todd class of the virtual tangent bundle capped with the fundamental class. Provided, GRR in the form above fails to hold for these new Todd classes, but still.

Comment: In fact the Baum-Fulton-MacPhearson Riemann-Roch theory seems to me to be an argument for writing the theorem in the first version, aka. as exhibiting a natural transformation: that is the version that generalizes to nonsingular varieties and even to separated schemes of finite type over a field.

Comment: Only a comment instead of an answer, but in the introduction of SGA 6 they write that they will use the second formulation because it is "more useful for their needs". I'm not familiar with this part of SGA 6 so I can't say exactly why how this is true, but maybe an answer is to be found there :-)